# SQL Server char and nchar columns search differently

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have a strange problem.  We are upgrading JDE and the database schema is changing - some char columns are changing to nchar types.  However, we have found that some of the searches are no longer working, and we have found this to be consistent across our SQL Server 2008 databases:

In the DB that I tested, the ItemNumber column is a char(25) and has varying length contents.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ItemNumber LIKE '%S'
```

returns a bunch of rows.  However, if we change the column to an nchar(25) that query now only returns those rows that have an ItemNumber value ending in "S" *and* are 25 characters long, so it seems that trailing spaces are now being (possibly correctly) taken into account - if you change the wildcard value to '%S ' it finds 24 character item numbers ending in "S".

Obviously, this is quite an issue for us as *S searches no longer work in JDE, as the underlying database calls now need every nchar column to be trimmed.  Is this a known issue, or a setting somewhere that we need to change?

*Additional Information*
We don't have any control over the column types used, nor can we change the underlying SQL generated, as this is part of our ERP system and its upgrade.  We have logged a call with Oracle, but as far as I am aware they haven't seen this, nor can they replicate it (but we don't know under what circumstances they are trying to do this), plus the fact that it happens across our other databases/servers makes me wonder if it isn't an obscure setting, somewhere.

Comment: Why are you using char or nchar instead of varchar or nvarchar? And why - if you have changed it to Unicode - are you not prefixing your string correctly (`WHERE ItemNumber LIKE N'%S';`)?

Comment: I would not use char or nchar unless the filed was reuired to bea certain length (like 2 digit statecodes) Otherwise you will need to trim which is just wasting processing power when you could avoid them by using a varchar or nvarchar type.  This is a design change you need to make not a coding change.

Comment: See the additional information I updated, above - we have no control over the data types used (in fact, I agree with you and have never understood why they were set as char).  Again, like you, I thought of the N prefix on the search but:- a) this didn't make a difference and b) I don't think that solution would help us, anyway, as we can't change (AFAIK) the underlying SQL generation.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the N prefix as a fix to this issue. I was suggesting the N prefix as a general best practice and to avoid unexpected implicit conversions which can be real performance killers.

Comment: No, please don't get me wrong - it was a perfectly fair and correct point, and I thank you for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation for [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

> When you use Unicode data (nchar or nvarchar data types) with LIKE, trailing blanks are significant; however, for non-Unicode data, trailing blanks are not significant.

I reproduced your problem with the following table:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(x NCHAR(25));
INSERT @t SELECT N'nanaS';
SELECT x FROM @t WHERE x LIKE N'%S';
```

Result:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

However if you use `NVARCHAR` instead, this problem does not occur:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(x NVARCHAR(25));
INSERT @t SELECT N'nanaS';
SELECT x FROM @t WHERE x LIKE N'%S';
```

Results:

```
x
-----
nanaS
```

However the original table didn't produce the desired results even if converting to `NVARCHAR` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(x NCHAR(25));
INSERT @t SELECT N'nanaS';
SELECT x FROM @t WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25),x) LIKE N'%S';
```

Result:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

So one potential workaround would be to use the right data type in the first place (and also always prefix Unicode strings `N'properly'`. If you can't make the data type correct, you can use the `RTRIM()` workaround posted by Aushin, but keep HLGEM's comments in mind as well.

Comment: For clarity I think when the documentation refers to trailing spaces in the `NVARCHAR` type it is referring to explicit trailing spaces (i.e. the space at the end of `'Test '`), rather than implicit trailing spaces due to the length of the type (since it is of variable length). So I don't think the behavious contradicts the documentation, although the documentation is not very clear. This is demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62d69/1), where the 3rd row has `'A '` in the `NVARCHAR` column and is not like '%A'.

Comment: Ah, that's very interesting - I've been searching for information like that but I've struggled to find anything mentioning it. Can't believe I didn't think to just check the LIKE man page. I *totally* agree with you that the column should be an nvarchar, but we have *no* control over the DB table setup.  I can't believe this isn't happening to other people - by the looks of things I'm guessing this isn't something I can turn it off.

Comment: @MadHalfling it probably has happened to other people, and they simply stopped using NCHAR. Not everyone is bound to bad design. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I meant with JDE - AFAIK it's got a fairly decent user base, and I can't imagine that we're alone in using MS SQL Server with it.

Comment: Does anyone know if this also applies to Oracle?  I found some Oracle documentation on LIKE at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm#i1034153 but it doesn't seem to mention, either way, how it treats such suffixes

Comment: @AaronBertrand Also: yup, I totally agree with you that it's bad design - their item *description* columns are also 2 (n)char(25) ones - I've NO bloody idea WHY they would do that. They do seem to have used (n)char rather than (n)varchar columns across the board, for some reason - maybe there's that reason is lost in the annals of history and it's become too difficult to change.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: My explanation below was based of a misreading of your question.  While RTRIM will work, I did not realize you weren't using nvarchar but char.  Aaron and Gordon have provided better insight.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE RTRIM(ItemNumber) LIKE N'%S'
```

> This is because for an nvarchar(25), the last character of 
>       'S'  is S.
>
> For nchar(25), 'S' is actually 'S' + 24 spaces. So your last character
>   is a space.

Comment: Please use the N prefix `LIKE N'%S'`

Comment: Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Trailing spaces are not significant on the LHS of a `LIKE`. e.g. `select 1 where 'X' + SPACE(24) like '%X'` returns `1`

Comment: I'm sorry, should I be deleting this answer?  I must have misread something.

Comment: Ah yes I did misread.   Is it protocol to delete my answer?  Haven't dealt with this before.  RTRIM solves the issue, but it's a bad explanation of what's happening.

Comment: I'd leave it. My earlier comment was based on [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626) but seems that doesn't cover the different semantics for unicode data.