# Select where like nchar or nvarchar

Tags: c#, sql, nvarchar

From my experience it seems that select where like on data from my database doesnt work on fields in nchar format but does in nvarchar format. Is this true?

If so why and is changing the data type to nvarchar the only work around?

I have noticed that nchar is of ANSIString type and nvarchar is just String but that seems odd that one works and the other doesnt when they're both unicode.

Comment: When you are searching for `nchar` are you accounting for the spaces at the end of the string? For example for the word "Hello" using `nvarchar(6)` would have it be `"Hello"` while `nchar(6)` would have it be `"Hello "`

Comment: Along these lines, you can try putting '%' at the end of your comparison string in the like clause which will also account for unlimited spaces (along with anything else after your comparison string of course)

Comment: To the idiot who voted to close this, go away, back to the depths of your basement. To the OP, is cast(column as varchar) that unwieldy? I've never tried using like with nchar, but it's most likely that you're not accounting for the fact that nchar fields are space padded, as Scott noted.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no I arent accounting for spaces. Well I never thought I was apparently I am

Comment: @nycdan I am yes like so `'%' + @field + '%'`

Comment: Well then you are accounting for padding at the end so that's not your problem.  Why not post your exact code and we'll see if that helps.

Comment: @Chris cheers for that yeah neither have I this was the first time i'd witnessed it, it's not a datatype i've used often in honest

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server char and nchar columns search differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171177/sql-server-char-and-nchar-columns-search-differently)

Comment: similar @MartinSmith but the answers I received on here were not on there, some similar answers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you were all pretty much on the money, it is a padding related issue an nchar or char has one space to right of it as padding which means I'd have to do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE '%bb %'
```

Instead of this

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE '%' + @field + '%'
```

This works the other way round to the latter query will select all fields that are nvarchar etc. but wont select fields that are nchar or char.

(EDIT)

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE '%bb%'
```

This solution will work on both sets of data types I have mentioned. No space needed after the bb

Comment: Glad you worked it out but I have a question.  Do you need the space between bb and %?  I wouldn't have thought so.

Comment: Good spot I'll edit that so the first solution will work for all data types I require cheers @nycdan

Comment: if your problem with arabic language , or any other Unicode try N'' + @param + N'' try or N'%' + @ param + N'%'